# How to stop my cat from biting me when I'm sleeping

Tags: cats, behavior, biting

My cat, a 2 year old rag doll who my husband says he is totally besotted with me, has been biting me. Not in play (I could understand that), but launching himself at me. The first time he bit me in the neck while I was dozing, getting over an illness, then he bit me in the arm, and just this morning he bit me on the face, again while I was dozing. These are real bites and drawing blood. I'm so upset because I adore him so much, but I have a few controlled illnesses and an infection could send me to hospital.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your cat under any unusual stress, is he neutered, and does he get much exersize or active play?

Comment: We could use a little more information that would help the answer be more helpful. Meg asked several good questions, and here is one more: what have you been doing about this so far? What has your response been? Have you laid still and hoped he went away? Have you given him food to distract him? Have you yelled or pushed him away?